# Doubt in a deduction to be used in proving a result in Analytic number theory

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am unable to prove a deduction which is to be used in proving Theorem 11.16 in Apostol introduction to analytic number theory.

I am adding image of result which I am unable to prove. Can someone please give a hint!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

$\sum_0^\infty x^{n+1}=\frac{x}{1-x}$.

Differentiate, multiply by $x$ then differentiate again.

However, the middle term in Apostol's answer is wrong, it should be minus his answer.